# Post failing with a nested resource from Ember.js to a Rails API.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a nested resource called App.Routine that has_many activities. When I send the post here is my payload:

{routine: {name:testName,activities:[{name:testName},{name:testName}]}}

This returns a 500 error:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RoutinesController#create

Activity(#32627220) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#33577656)

My Rails API is using ActiveModelSerializers:

```
class RoutineSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :activities, embed: :ids
end

class RoutinesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    routine = Routine.create(params[:routine])
  end
```

I believe my problem lies with how I handle the create action in my routines_controller.rb. Rails isn't liking how I am returning the hash of activities inside the routine JSON, but I can't figure out the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Did you ever solve this. Got a similar problem?

Comment: @Pedr - Unfortunately no. It does seem to be an issue with Rails not accepting the JSON I am sending. If I remove the {embedded: 'always'} from the App.store, 2 separate JSON posts are sent for the parent and child with the child having a 'parent_id'. Submitting my POSTs this way are successful, however I would like to just send the 1 post with the embedded parent/child objects. Following this example [https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example) and I can't figure out what I am doing different that would cause the error.

Comment: Finally figured this out. I was able to workaround by not embedding the child objects in the parent, so sending separate POSTs to the API once for the parent, then again for each child which included a parent_id. This was not an ideal solution so I went back to working on an embedded parent/child json request. My original problem was indeed with my Rails API. I followed @dgeb's example again and realized I didn't know much about strong parameters. Thankfully there's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters) for that! Once I implemented that correctly I'm good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original problem was indeed with my Rails API. I followed @dgeb's example again and realized I didn't know much about strong parameters. Thankfully there's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters) for that! Once I implemented that correctly I'm good to go!

Added 'gem strong_parameters' to my Gemfile. Then, my #create function on the parent controller makes a call to the update_parameters function where I first create and save the parent, then iterate through the child and save it.

From Dan Gebhart's ember data example:

```
def permitted_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name,
                                :last_name,
                                :email,
                                :notes,
                                phone_numbers: [:id, :number])
end

def update_contact(contact)
  contact_params = permitted_params
  phone_numbers_param = contact_params.extract!(:phone_numbers)
  phone_numbers_param = phone_numbers_param[:phone_numbers]
  phone_numbers_param ||= []

  # Because updates to the contact and its associations should be atomic,
  # wrap them in a transaction.
  Contact.transaction do
    # Update the contact's own attributes first.
    contact.attributes = contact_params
    contact.save!

    # Update the contact's phone numbers, creating/destroying as appropriate.
    specified_phone_numbers = []
    phone_numbers_param.each do |phone_number_params|
      if phone_number_params[:id]
        pn = contact.phone_numbers.find(phone_number_params[:id])
        pn.update_attributes(phone_number_params)
      else
        pn = contact.phone_numbers.create(phone_number_params)
      end
      specified_phone_numbers << pn
    end
  contact.phone_numbers.each do |pn|
    pn.destroy unless specified_phone_numbers.include?(pn)
  end
  end

  # Important! Reload the contact to ensure that changes to its associations
  # (i.e. phone numbers) will be serialized correctly.
  contact.reload

  return true
  rescue
  return false
  end
```